# Корректное использование Apache HTTP Client в многопоточном приложении

Tags: java, многопоточность, httpclient

Есть Java приложение, основная деятельность которого - автоматизированная работа в интернете со многих аккаунтов одновременно(НЕ спам или другая плохая деятельность). Для работы с сетью используется Apache HTTP Client 4.5.2. Приложение ходит в интернет через разные HTTP proxy(на 1 прокси 2 аккаунта) с авторизацией по логин/пароль, а так же использует куки.

Изначально, в силу очень плохих знаний Java, среды разработки, и, самое главное, английского языка, работа многопоточного приложения была построена следующим образом:

Выбираем из CSV файла(примитивный аналог Базы Данных) аккаунт, создаем для него отдельный поток, в котором создаем объект класса Task, в котором реализована основной функционал программы(парсинг полученных страниц и принятие решений на основе полученных данных, а так же обновление CSV файла). В этом объекте(классе) в свою очередь, создается объект класса Network, в котором осуществляется вся работа с сетью(а полученные данные используются в Task).

Таким образом, для каждого потока создается свой экземпляр HTTP Client. 
Когда я это делал, я уже примерно знал, что у HttpClient есть особенности работы в многопоточной среде, но мне казалось что создание отдельного экземпляра для каждого потока является оптимальным решение этой проблемы.

И этот код даже вполне сносно работал, пока потоков было не очень много. Каким то чудом, ну или я просто не замечал ошибки, т.к. их было мало.

Но когда потоков стало достаточно много, код перестал работать корректно, что вполне естественно. А именно, при начале работы программы, запускаются все потоки, но достаточно быстро большинство из них уходит в Ожидание(блокировку), создаваемую HttpClient и не работает(грубо говоря, зависает).

Естественно, я обратился к Гуглу и документации, и почти сразу понял, что создавать отдельный экземпляр HTTP Client для каждого потока нельзя, а нужно создавать один на все приложение, и использовать

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
```

Но при этом для каждого потока создавать свой `HttpContext` (в нем, если не путаю, хранятся куки + в моем случае авторизация на прокси(использую preemptive способ авторизации)).

Подробнее об этом можно прочесть в [документации HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e405), так же там есть пример, рекомендую глянуть для того, что бы было понтянее о чем спрашиваю дальше.

В целом все понятно. Но как сделать это конкретно в моем приложении, с учетом его архитектуры, описанной выше?
Оно специально было так сделано, что бы хоть как то быть правильным с точки зрения ООП, с задумкой повторного использования отдельных классов в других приложениях.

Конечно, можно сделать все - и выбор аккаунта(и создание потока если он подоходит), и основную логику работы приложения, и работу с сетью в одном классе, создавая HTTP Client один раз. Но это выйдет класс огромных размеров, читать и редактировать который будет очень неудобно, а использовать в других приложениях - практически невозможно. Мне кажется, что это категорически неправильно с точки зрения ООП, и так делать нельзя.

Как же тогда правильно решить эту задачу?

Пока писал свой вопрос, в голову пришла идея, что можно один раз создавать создавать HTTP Client в классе, где выбирается аккаунт, а потом просто передавать его так:

```
public GetThread(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, HttpGet httpget)
```

в каждый поток, а там уже передавать аналогичным способ в класс Network, и работать с ним.

Тогда, по идее должна сохраниться структура программы, и при этом не будет проблем с многопоточностью у HTTP Client.

Верно ли я думаю? Если нет, то как будет правильно?

P.S. Это мое первое серьезное приложение на Java, пожалуйста, не судите строго, все приходит с опытом. Заранее искренне благодарю за ответы и посильную помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно **главная загвоздка** производительности в чем? Насколько я понял, в том, что Вы одновременно создаете много потоков. Одновременное создание большого количества потоков, как вы уже поняли, накладно.

В хорошей многопоточной программе есть некий фиксированный пул потоков, который обслуживает систему. Например:

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //делаем свои дела
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Runnable task = new Task();
        executor.execute(task);
    }
}
```

В этом примере одновременно будут выполняться не более 4 задач одновременно.

**Проблема номер два.** Допустим вы убрали ручное создание огромного кол-ва потоков и используете пул с 4 потоками. Но так как вы работаете с сетью, вы ждете ответ с сервера. В данном месте поток блокируется, переходит в ожидание:

```
public void run() {
    Response response = client.execute(...);
}
```

Очевидно, что в случае долгого ответа сервера, производительность будет плоха, а процессор не будет нагружен, так как вы просто ждете.

Для решения подобных проблем, например, написали [Non-blocking I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)). В случае с http клиентами тоже есть не блокирующие библиотеки, например [async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client):

```
public void run() {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("https://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
        }

    }); 
}
```

После вызова `get`, текущий поток не блокируется и мы благополучно выходим из метода `run`, а ответ приходит в `onSuccess`. Внутри подобные библиотеки устроены таким образом, что в них есть некий пул потоков, обслуживающий выполнение запросов, а в случае ожидания ответа сервера, поток не блокируется, а идет обслуживать другой запрос. Как-то так :)

В apache http client тоже есть неблокирующее апи [example](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpClient.java). Правда думаю, что если делать через nio, то проще какую-нибудь популярную библиотеку заюзать.